# Inner .each()-loop with .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, append, each

I have an array of projects. Projects can have subprojects, hence the field parent_id. 
I want to show a list of subprojects and for each subproject i want to "preview" the prio1 subprojects of that subproject.

So i have two .each()-loops and use .append() to add the HTML (INNER AND OUTER).

For some reason the preview subprojects come out on top of the list instead of inside the project-div.

Any ideas what i do wrong?

```
        var filterdata = this.get_subprojects(project_id);
      // **** OUTER LOOP *******
        filterdata.forEach(function(project) {
            var subprojects = projectList.get_subprojects(project.project_id, 1);

        $("#projects>.list").append(
        '<div class="project">'

            +'<div class="left">'
                +'<img class="prio-icon" src="img/prio'+project.prio+'.png"/>'
                +'<img class="type-icon" src="img/type'+project.type+'.png"/>'
            +'</div>'

            +'<div class="right">'
                +'<div class="title">'+project.title+'</div>'
                +'<div class="next_action_div" >');

            //*** INNER LOOP LOOP FOR PREVIEW *****
                subprojects.forEach(function(subproject,1) {
                    $("#projects>.list").append(
                    +'<span class="next_action">'+subproject.title+'</span>');                

                });

            $("#projects>.list").append(
                '</div>'
            +'</div><!-- end center -->'
             +'<div style="clear:both;"></div>'
        +'</div> <!-- end subitem -->');
        return $("#projects>.list").html();
        });
```

Comment: Would you mind making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) out of this? It would make it a lot easier for us to test, and change the code for you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `.append` sections of HTML like that. The [`HTMLstring`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString) [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) accepts expects proper HTLM content. Tags in that string automatically get closed.

Try this instead:

```js
$('#container').append('<div id="outer">Outer div</div>');
$("#outer").append("<div>Inner div</div>"); // As example why your code doesn't work:
$("#outer").append("<div>Broken div (Check the rendered HTML, the tag will be fixed)");
```

```css
div{
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Okay, I guess i put it all in a string first then. That should solve it, right?